# Invalid access key error using credentials redeemed from an amazon open id token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm getting `Invalid access key` error using credentials redeemed from an amazon open id token from cognito

Here's what I'm doing

1. Get developer authenticated open id token

   cognito.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, function (err, data)     {

   openIdToken = data.credentials
   });
2. Redeem open id token for security credentials, I set the params to the congnito Auth role and set an arbitrary role session name.  I use the token from step 1.  There is no place where I set the identity id from step 1.

   ```
   it('should be able to exchange temporary open id token for auth credentials', function (done) {

       var sts = new AWS.STS();
       var params = {
           RoleArn: roleArn,
           RoleSessionName: 'photo-upload-session',
           WebIdentityToken: openIdToken.Token
       };
       sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
           should.not.exist(err);

           should.exist(data.Credentials.AccessKeyId);
           should.exist(data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey);
           should.exist(data.Credentials.SessionToken);
           credentials = data.Credentials;

           done();
       });


   });
   ```
3. I update the current credentials

   `AWS.config.update({accessKeyId : credentials.AccessKeyId, secretAccessKey:credentials.SecretAccessKey});`
4. I upload a file to s3 and get the `[InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.]` error

*edit using Bob Kinney's advice I tried two methods - setting the sessionToken (which worked) and using the Congito credentials which gave a TypeError not a buffer error.  The CognitoIdentityCredentials example is below.

```
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
       IdentityPoolId:config.get('aws_identity_pool_id'),
       Logins: {
         'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': openIdToken.Token
       }
    });

    var body = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/test_photo.jpg');

    var s3obj = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'test-uploads', Key: 'test'}});

    s3obj.upload({Body: body}).
        on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
        send(function(err, data) {
            should.not.exist(err);
            done();

        });
```

** update

So moving back to the java client error, we are using the openid token (which was tested to be working correctly with the sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity) and passing that token into an extension of AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider (code taken from this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/) - then using that identity to upload to s3 getting the error

```
CustomAwsIdentityProvider provider = CustomAwsIdentityProvider.newInstance(this, BuildConfig.AWS_COGNITO_POOL_ID, Regions.US_EAST_1);

CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(this, provider, Regions.US_EAST_1);

TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);
tm.upload("my-upload", uuid.toString(), file);
```

Comment: Can you please include the complete code you used for each step? Please make sure you review the "Developer Authenticated Identities Authflow" at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/authentication-flow/ . This clarifies each call to Cognito and whether the call comes from the device or your backend server.

Comment: ok updated with example for step 2

Comment: Have you made sure your policy grants read/write permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the issues. It appears you are using the JavaScript SDK. When using this flow you can use the standard `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` object as mentioned in the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html#Configuring_AWS_CognitoIdentityCredentials) using the key of `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com` and the value as the OpenId Connect token returned from the `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` call.

The reason for the error you are seeing is that you are not including the sessionToken from the STS result. Using the `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` object should resolve this for you.

**Update 2015-07-21:** There is a small issue in the SDK that will unfortunately prevent  `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` from working as I described it. We are working on mitigating this issue.

**Update 2015-07-24:** You should be able to use the following to use the `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` with your developer authenticated identiity:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'MY_IDENTITY_POOL',
  IdentityId: data.IdentityId,
  Logins: {
    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': data.Token
  }
});
```

Where data is the response from `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity`.

Comment: Would I be using the congitocredentials object as well with the android and ios mobile sdks in the same way?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey, no, please refer to our [end-to-end example](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) for an example of using developer authenticated identities on iOS and Android.

Comment: gives me this error  Uncaught AssertionError: expected [TypeError: Not a buffer] to not exist
      at _stream_readable.js:908:16 when i call s3 upload with this credentials

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Please include your code to upload to S3 in this question or open a new one. This error sounds unrelated to the credentials.

Comment: added the s3 upload code - it works fine if I use the my default aws server credentials - but errors if I try to use the cognito identity credentials

Comment: is this how you want me to set the cognitocredentials?      `AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                IdentityPoolId:poolId,
                Logins: {
                    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': openIdToken.Token

                }
            });`

Comment: It seems to work if I set the sessionToken property in the aws config rather than using the cognitoidneitycredentials

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Are you using the Browser SDK or NodeJS? Which version?

Comment: we are using node.js server side

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey I've just confirmed with the one of the JS SDK developers and the buffer error is usually an indication that the file is an unrecognized type and shouldn't be affected by the credentials. There is a problem with what I suggested in using the AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials that would prevent that from working. This should hopefully be addressed soon.

Comment: it's a misleading error because the buffer error only occurs when using the congitoidentity credentials - when i set the credentials manually to the one derived from STS it works fine.  It says it's a buffer error but I suspect it's actually failing much earlier somewhere else.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the java android sdk client code - since that's ultimately what we'll need to get working on our project.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your update. What error are you seeing on Android?

Comment: @BobKinney Thank you this helped me a lot.  Basically, this means that in your [blog post part 4](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2323YHCM0I7OO/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-4-Enhanced-Flow) one should use `new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials()` instead of `getCredentialsForIdentity()` Also please mention in the answer, that one must call `AWS.config.credentials.get(callback)` and the credentials are set in the callback.  That wasn't clear (understatement :) ).