# AWSCognito Login Provider Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Soo I'm a bit slow and according to the docs it says

```
"Logins - A map of logins for this identity. As with GetId and 
GetOpenIdToken, you can supply any supported public
 provider token, but you can additionally supply a user 
identifier keyed by the developer provider name that 
you set when you created the identity pool.This should be 
a unique identifier for this user in your system."
```

I already added my login provider when creating my identity pool but I'm getting this error when accessing AWS Cognito.

```
"InvalidParameterException: Please specify at least one login provider"
```

Is my Login Provider the problem? The login provider key matches the key I added when creating my IdentityPool

```
var params = {
   IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:2e90e469-c81a-4936-b78a-7071e79b3032', /* required */
   Logins: { /* required */
   "login.appName.myapp": 'userIdentifier',
   /* anotherKey: ... */
},
  IdentityId: null,
  TokenDuration: 1
};
```

The value for "login.appName.myapp" is a unique generated string which I believe should be okay.

**------------------------UPDATE----------------------**

```
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

var params = {
 IdentityPoolId:'us-east-1:2e90e469-c81a-4936-b78a-7071e79b3032',
 Logins: {

 },
 IdentityId: null,
 TokenDuration: 1
};
 cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
 if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
 else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I've been using this aws docs as reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're making this call with the JavaScript SDK, try using the code [Bob provided in his recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525039/51061).

**Update:**
In the Logins map that you're passing to getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity in your updated code sample above, you need to add a key and a value. The key should be the name of the developer provider that you have added in the console for your identity pool. The value should be an identifier that you use to uniquely identify the user (any unique identifier you choose such as a user id or an email address).

Comment: Yep I'm using javascript. Thanks for the reference, so it looks like Bob says to call getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity, get the token, and then pass the token into the Logins for AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials. My code is above on how this looks but I'm now getting the same error when calling getOpenIdTOkenForDeveloperIdentity, does this have something to do with my identity pool on my AWS Account?

Comment: The additional code and context are helpful. See my updated response above. If you're still having issues keep responding and we'll help you get to the bottom of it!

Comment: perfect :) thanks a lot! I got a response back from getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdeneity